# XposedBridge not loading my class

Tags: android, xposed, xposed-framework

This is my first go at writing an Xposed module, so I followed the tutorial to a tee.  It took quite awhile before everything was setup properly, but when I run it, it doesn't load my class.

```
01-04 20:45:43.001 18383-18383/? I/Xposed:
 Loading modules from /data/app/com.germainz.activityforcenewtask-1/base.apk 
01-04 20:45:43.013 18383-18383/? I/Xposed:
 Loading class com.germainz.activityforcenewtask.XposedMod 
01-04 20:45:43.015 18383-18383/? I/Xposed:
 Loading modules from /data/app/com.almostinteractive.swypearrows-1/base.apk 
01-04 20:45:43.084 18383-18383/? I/Xposed:
 Loading modules from /data/app/com.danation.xposed.swypetweaks-1/base.apk 
01-04 20:45:43.115 18383-18383/? I/Xposed:
 Loading class com.danation.xposed.swypetweaks.SwypeTweaks
```

and indeed, no logs are every output from

```
public void handleLoadPackage(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam loadPackageParam) throws Throwable {
    XposedBridge.log("-------- LOADED " + loadPackageParam.packageName);
}
```

I've zipped up the whole Android Studio project and put it up on GDrive here:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eWVxxMd5Ty9OF7gNCMn_cT_E5FDOgnVI

I'm testing on a Nexus 5X running Nougat 7.1.2 and Xposed version 89.

Really, I've looked and haven't found anything sufficiently similar to help me fix this.  Any help you guys could give me would be incredible.

Comment: Mmm, did you activated your module?